# Prove that function is constant-is this proof?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

Prove that the function is constant with x.

$$f(x,t) = A^2e^{2i\frac{px-Et}{h}}$$

So since we assume that t is constant, I tried to prove this using:
$$\frac{df}{dx}=\lim\limits_{a \to 0}\frac{f(x+a)-f(x)}{a}=0$$

$$\frac{df}{dx}=\lim\limits_{a \to 0}\frac{A^2e^{2i\frac{px+pa-Et}{h}}-A^2e^{2i\frac{px-Et}{h}}}{a}=\lim\limits_{a \to 0}\frac{A^2e^{2i\frac{px+Et}{h}}(e^{\frac{2ipa}{h}}-1)}{a}=0$$
because 
$$\lim\limits_{a \to 0}e^{\frac{2ipa}{h}}=1$$

I am not sure if this is right or can be done in some other way, I woul really appreciate help :)

Comment: You basically claim $\lim_{x\to{}0}\frac{e^{ax}-1}{x}=0$ which isn't the case since this as expected gives $\lim_{x\to{}0}\frac{e^{ax}-1}{x}=\frac{de^{ax}}{dx}|_{x=0}=a$

Comment: Is x actually supposed to be an integer in this case ? If you don’t have x an integer, there’s really no hope this is constant

Comment: @Robo300 well the exercise doesnt specifiy but since this should be a wave function, I dont think x is an integer

Comment: Oh, a wave function, so what you really want to prove is that you get a constant when you multiply it by its complex conjugate,

Comment: Can you edit the answer with more information? You say it's a wave function, do you know more?

Comment: @Robo300 ohhhhhh... I get it now, I am an idiot lol I didnt realize. Thank you all so much for your time :)